# NullPointerException on gephi SVG export

Tags: svg, gephi

Similarly to [this forum thread](https://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?t=3128), I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when exporting a graph to SVG. It doesn't happen with all graphs, but once it happens for a particular graph, no amount of closing and re-opening the `.gephi` file will let me export.

Unlike the forum thread, getting rid of spaces in node labels doesn't help me. In the log file, there's a very suspicious line:

```
***** CSSEngine: exception property.syntax.error:org.w3c.dom.DOMException: The "stroke-width" property does not support dimension values.

AttrValue:3.7186165E-4

Exception:org.w3c.dom.DOMException
```

Since SVG is all about web pages, this looks like a plausible issue. [This forum post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-batik-users/200401.mbox/%3C95EA2B9D9300D711958E00508BCF33C7035815B4@TOCOMEXC30%3E) seems relevant. Here's a quote from it:

> Batik is correct in rejecting the content, although it is a bit
>   confused in the error message.  'stroke-width' is a CSS property and
>   as such can not use scientific notation, as you quoted (silly yes, but
>   that is what CSS2 has said for a long time). The error comes because
>   Batik is trying to interpret 'e-03' as a unit (like 'em' for example).

Any thoughts on how I can export my beautiful Gephi image to SVG?

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug: https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/697

Answer (score 1):

The number values in SVG properties (as with CSS properties) do not support scientific notation.

The error message indicates that somewehere in your file you have that `stroke-width` value (`3.7186165E-4`).

This is obviously a bug in the gephi SVG exporter. You should report it to them.

In the meantime you could fix it with a text editor.  In the above example you would need to find the element with:

```
stroke-width="3.7186165E-4"
```

and change it so that it doesn't use scientific notation:

```
stroke-width="0.00037186165"
```

Note that if there is one, there may be others.  Hopefully not too many!  Note that other occurrences may not necessarily be on a stroke-width attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this! Would that it were that easy. `.gephi` files are not plain-text so I can't edit manually. I'll go ahead and report a bug to the Gephi team.

Comment: If they are .svgz files, then they are just gzipped text files. You should be able to run them through an online gzip program to get the plain svg text file.